# No controls visible in Google Cloud Datalab?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Why do the controls in the Google Cloud Datalab sometimes disappear? I'm using latest Chrome build on OSX:

[image]

At the top, where there should be "Run", "Insert code" buttons etc, there's nothing.

Refreshing does not help.

The console panel shows this:

[image]

Is this just a 'being in beta' thing?

Anyway, thought I'd flag it up here in case the authors don't know about it.

Comment: Ah, looks like it only happens at smaller screen resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. It happens if the browser width is too small. It will be fixed in next release.